# Accessing state in middleware in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a middleware in my React/Redux app that looks like this:

```
export const myMiddleware = (store) => (next) => async (action) => {

   switch (action.type) {
      case types.SOME_ACTION:
      // Some logic here...
      break;
   }
}
```

I need to access the state here so that I can execute my logic this middleware is  designed to handle.

I thought, because store is being passed into the middleware, I could access it but when I inspect store, I don't see the state at all. I do see a `getState()` function but when I used it, looks like it's getting me the initial state, not the current state with data in it.

Here's the `store` object I see when I inspect it:
[image]

Here's my store and how I include the middleware in it:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/root-reducer';
import { myMiddleware } from '../middleware/my-middleware';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {

    const store = createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        applyMiddleware(thunk, myMiddleware)
    );

    return store;
}
```

How do I access state in my middleware?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the updated state (after the current action) in the middleware, if you use `getState()` inside an async callback (signalR response for example). In this case, I've used `setTimeout()` to simulate an async action.

**Note:**

1. Although this works in theory, this is not a good idea. There is no guarantee that other actions haven't changed the state. In the example, you can see that the middleware shows the end state of both dispatched actions, for both actions.
2. Regarding the discussion in the comments - simple state changes should be done in the reducer, and not in the middleware.

```js
const { createStore, applyMiddleware } = Redux;

const DEMO_ACTION = 'DEMO_ACTION';

const demoAction = (payload) => ({
  type: DEMO_ACTION,
  payload
});

const myMiddleware = ({ getState }) => (next) => async (action) => {
  setTimeout( // simulates an async action
    () => console.log(action.payload, getState())
  , 0);
   
  next(action);
}

const initialState = { data: [] };

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch(type) {
    case DEMO_ACTION:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: [...state.data, payload]
      };
  }
  
  return state;
}

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(myMiddleware)
);

store.dispatch(demoAction('data1'));
store.dispatch(demoAction('data2'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.0/redux.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I'm accepting yours as the answer even though, as you're suggesting, it's not the right approach. I'm looking into creating an orchestration to handle each side effect through `observables`. I think this may give me the chain of events that I need to implement while handling each state change in the `reducer`. It feels as if this approach would create additional data points in my store as well as a few additional steps but creates an orchestration process with simple individual steps.

Comment: Another orchestration option is redux saga. Check other state management as well, such as MobX.

Comment: @OriDrori in myMiddleware - Can we access the corresponding state for the current action alone ?