# Persist data with redux in angular

Tags: angular, redux

I'm using redux with angular, but when I reload the page I lose the store, how can I persist this data when the page is reloaded?

Comment: Need to look at local storage for persisting reloads. https://medium.com/@jrcreencia/persisting-redux-state-to-local-storage-f81eb0b90e7e or something along those lines.

Comment: You could also use Firebase + Cookies/Local Storage if you want the store information to persist beyond an individuals computer. Probably overkill though and Local Storage alone would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

I Understand it's an old question but Since this has wasted a lot of my time so i'm going to leave this here incase someone is looking for it.

> Notice: I am using @angular-redux/store (from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-redux/store))  with this solution

**store.ts**

Inside the store create a function that loads the `state` from the `localStorage` if it exists and a Custom middleware that saves the `state` into the `localStorage` whenever an action is dispatched

```
import {
  IAuthInterface,
  AUTH_INITIAL_STATE, 
  authReducer,  
} from './app/reducers/authReducer';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
export interface IAppState {
  auth: IAuthInterface;
}

export const INITIAL_STATE: IAppState = {
  auth: AUTH_INITIAL_STATE
};

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
});

// Get Value from LocalStorage variable if it exists  
export const loadState = () => {
  try {
    const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
    if (serializedState === null) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return JSON.parse(serializedState);
  } catch (err) {
    return undefined;
  }
}; 
// Create Middleware to Save State when an action is dispatched
export const PersistMiddleware = ({ getState }) => (next) => async (action) => {
  setTimeout(  () => { //used to simulate async action
      const serializedState = JSON.stringify(getState());
      localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);
    }, 0);
  next(action);
}


const State = loadState();
export const persistedState = State ? State : INITIAL_STATE;
```

**app.module.ts**

Inside the app module Make the neccessary Imports

```
 import {
      NgRedux,
      NgReduxModule,
      DevToolsExtension,
     } from '@angular-redux/store';
 import { 
      IAppState,
      rootReducer,
      persistedState,
      PersistMiddleware
     } from   'src/store'; //store.ts file
```

and pass your custom middleware and state to the store

```
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>, devtools: DevToolsExtension) {
    ngRedux.configureStore(
      rootReducer,
      persistedState,
      [PersistMiddleware],
      [devtools.enhancer()]
    );
  }
}
```

**sources used:**

[For loadState Method](https://medium.com/@jrcreencia/persisting-redux-state-to-local-storage-f81eb0b90e7e)

[For Custom Middleware](https://blog.webiks.com/angular-redux-middleware/)

[Also For Custom Middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51387425/9871756)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this module to implement redux persist state 
https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage

Implementation

```
npm install ngrx-store-localstorage --save
```

UPDATE FOR NGRX 4

Wrap localStorageSync in an exported function.
Include in your meta-reducers array in StoreModule.forRoot.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { StoreModule, ActionReducerMap, ActionReducer, MetaReducer } from '@ngrx/store';
import { localStorageSync } from 'ngrx-store-localstorage';
import { reducers } from './reducers';


const reducers: ActionReducerMap<IState> = {todos, visibilityFilter};

export function localStorageSyncReducer(reducer: ActionReducer<any>): ActionReducer<any> {
  return localStorageSync({keys: ['todos']})(reducer);
}
const metaReducers: Array<MetaReducer<any, any>> = [localStorageSyncReducer];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(
        reducers,
        {metaReducers}
    )
  ]
})
export class MyAppModule {}
```